# Why does it look like my object has 2 different materials even though it just has 1

Tags: modeling, materials, light, faces, lighting

These are some parts of the head of a model I'm making. I noticed there is a lighting problem and it makes it look like the indicated object has 2 different materials separated by an edge. It's just one material with smooth faces. Not sure what to do so any help would be great!

[image]


[image]

Comment: Did you check if the normals/Face_Orientation are facing outwards?

Comment: yep, face orientation is outwards and I recalculated normals outwards a few times. Didn't work

Comment: Would it be possible to share the blend file (redacted to just the part in question with material)? You can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: A degenerate face could be causing this, though I would expect it to show up in the solid view as well.